How to generate changelog in a devops build validation pipeline?
We have a pipeline that generates changelogs, and we would like to execute it in a DevOps Build validation once a PR is created with the target main.
This does not really work since once the pipeline runs, it creates commit and restarts the build validation pipeline again.
What are the best practices for that? Is it possible to find a way to automate the changelog generation?

After setting a pipeline to the "Build Validation" of branch policies for main branch, the pipeline will be automatically triggered by the following scenarios:

A new PR is created, and the target branch is main.
Every time when having new commits pushed to the source branch of an active PR that the target branch is main.

If you want the pipeline to be triggered only when new PR created with the target branch is main, you can consider using webhooks resource in the pipeline, instead of setting it as "Build Validation":

Go to "Project Settings" > "Service connections" to create an Incoming WebHook service connection. Set the customized "WebHook Name" (e.g., WebHookTrigger) and "Service connection name" (e.g., WebHookConnection).


Fill your Azure DevOps organization name and the webHook name into "https://dev.azure.com/<ADO Organization>/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/<WebHook Name>?api-version=6.0-preview" to get the request URL. For example.
https://dev.azure.com/myOrg/_apis/public/distributedtask/webhooks/WebHookTrigger?api-version=6.0-preview


Go to "Project Settings" > "Service Hooks" to create a Web Hooks.

On the Trigger section, select "Pull request created" as the trigger event, select the corresponding Repository and select main as the Target branch.
On the Action section, fill the request URL to the URL field.



In the pipeline, define a webhooks resource like as below. The value of connection should be the name of the Incoming WebHook service connection created above.
resources:
  webhooks:
  - webhook: resWebHook
    connection: WebHookConnection

. . .




